# Ruby web application working modes

Tags: php, ruby, web-applications, fastcgi

When I write web app on PHP it can works in different modes: like FCGI (php-fpm), like apache module (mod_php) and so on. In all this cases when I am editing my PHP scripts application updates immediatelly without need to restart a server. I know that Ruby web app also can works in different modes (i.e. FCGI withing Unicorn + Nginx). But I want to get an idea about all the most common ways to launch Ruby web app and techincal details about all this means (i.e. when I should restart my server to update scripts), their proc and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to write Ruby applications, classic 1990s-style CGI, FastCGI, independent HTTP-capable processes with [Mongrel](http://rubygems.org/gems/mongrel) or [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) and the more modern, recommended approach which uses a launcher like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) to manage the processes more directly.

Ruby on Rails can have several operating modes. The default two are `development` and `production`. These have some important differences:

In **development**:

- Anything in `app/` or `config/routes.rb` is reloaded for each request.
- The `log/development.log` is as verbose as possible, recording each query executed.
- Assets are served up in their raw form, can be changed any time.

In **production**:

- Application is loaded once and cached, any changes require a restart.
- The `log/production.log` file contains only errors and important notifications.
- Assets are minified, compressed, and served up in bundles. Even minor changes require repackaging everything.

It's generally a bad idea to be editing scripts on a production server, so the Rails approach is usually a good thing. If you need to rapidly iterate on something, do it on your local copy and push the changes to the server only when you're confident they'll work.

If you really need to emergency fix something on the server, you can edit the code, then `touch tmp/restart.txt` to force a reload. When you change assets you'll have to run `rake assets:precompile` to repackage them.

Like a lot of things, Rails makes the recommended approach easy and the risky one hard.

Comment: Great! Can you explain how RoR achieves such behavior in dev mode? It depends on used server and have diffenent implementations or it is server-independent feature? And what about other frameworks like Sinatra?

Comment: It's a feature of Rails. Sinatra is a lot more light-weight and doesn't have this by default, you need to restart your server, but you can always [add this on](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading) if you really want it.